# Where to ask about BUYING music

Tags: discussion, topics

I want to ask a question about BUYING music as a consumer. From the Tour of this site, I recognize this is off-topic, as it is not about MAKING music.

Where to ask about buying music?

Comment: [musicfans.se] *might* help, there's a question like [Is the Beatles catalog available as DRM-free downloads?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/927) on that site.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a Stack Exchange site for this topic.

The upside is that the internet already careers very well for this. Google (and other search engines) provide shopping searches, vendor ratings etc. so you should find everything you could need.

Comment: My question would be more about how to buy music generally, not about individual shops and ratings.

Comment: Yep, we don't have anything on that. The internet is literally full of that sort of thing, but it's all opinion based so would not fit on a Stack Exchange site.